# What's wrong with this listview statement?

Tags: android, android-listview

When I copy a code like this,

```
private ListView lstview1;  <--there is a yellow line beneth it. why?
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    ListView lstview1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,listView1);
      setListAdapter(adapter);
```

The last statement shows that The method setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter) is undefined for the type SecActivity
what's matter?

Comment: The yellow line is there because `lstview1` is never used.Does `SecActivity` extend `Activity` or `ListActivity`?

Comment: Android studio will also highlight spelling mistakes with yellow underlines - if you're using lstview1 else where, it might be because it isn't spelt listView1

Comment: thanks, I repeat definition. just same as Piyush said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because already you have declared ***lstview1*** varible globally and after that on onCreate() method you are also declared it again..

So first change:

```
lstview1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

And after that if your Activity is extends with only ***Activity*** then set adapter to ListView like:

```
lstview1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

OR

if it is extends with ***ListActivity*** then use

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your wonderful explanation. I shall vote again as soon as I get enough score to vote.

Comment: There is another new matter at 'code' lstview1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,listView1); the last item of listView1 was warnned that can not be resolved to a vairable with a red line beneth it. why?

Comment: At that place you have to pass there your String array or any other array list which you have declared. If you have not declared your arraylist with  listVie‌​w1 named variable then this types of error come.. So declared your arraylist globally with this name

Comment: the quick fix available also suggests that, I try to change it to lstview1, it seems can not do the trick.
I think I have used it at lstview1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

Comment: The listView1 is id of ListView defined in layout.xml file,    android:id="@+id/listView1"

Comment: When I did that, new problem occurred: The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(SecActivity, int, ListView) is undefined. I was suggested to change lstview1 to int type. or remove some arguments.

Comment: you haven't passed ur ListView object there. You have to pass your ArrayList Or ur String array in which your data will be show in ListView

Comment: I uderstand. the original code must have the value in the same activity, but mine is at another fold. I change it to R.array.listview1. and no any warning at all. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setAdapeter like this..`setListAdapter()` is not a method in the `Activity` it a method in the `ListActivity`

```
lstview1.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Comment: Thanks. I forget that.

Answer (score 1):

The yellow line probably says something like that your variable `lstview1` isn't used. That is because this line

```
ListView lstview1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

makes a *new* variable in another context. You probably meant

```
lstview1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Comment: thanks. I have not enough score at present, so sorry can not vote.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
 lstview1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

instead of :

```
  setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thanks. I have not enough score at present, so sorry can not vote.

Comment: There is another new matter at 'code'    lstview1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,listVie​w1);'code' the last item of listView1 was warnned that can not be resolved to a vairable with a red line beneth it. why?

Comment: Please add another answer or edit first post and format code. I don't understand where is the problem

Comment: look at the second comment of mine. I try to show lstview1=... as code format. according to suggestion below, 'code' but it seems no use, thus it is not comfortable to see. do I make it sense.